# How to use --directories-to-pull to save files created by app in Firebase Test Lab

Tags: firebase-test-lab

I'm using Firebase Test Lab to run integration tests of my app written in Flutter. I would like to pull all files created by the app and save it in the results bucket. It seems like the `--directories-to-pull` argument is what I need: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run#--directories-to-pull

I'm using the following code to run my tests:

```
gcloud firebase test android run \
    --type instrumentation \
    --app build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk \
    --test build/app/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk \
    --timeout 5m \
    --directories-to-pull /sdcard,/data/local/tmp
```

However, when using the argument `--directories-to-pull /sdcard,/data/local/tmp` some files are missing in the results bucket. Especially the logcat file is missing which is really important for debugging.

Without the `--directories-to-pull` argument I see the following results in my bucket:

[image: results in bucket without --directories-to-pull]

With `--directories-to-pull /sdcard,/data/local/tmp` I only see the following results in my bucket:

[image: results in bucket with --directories-to-pull]

**Questions:**

- How do I pull all data created by the app and save it in the results bucket?
- Am I using the `--directories-to-pull` argument correctly?
- Why are there fewer files in my results bucket when using the `--directories-to-pull` argument?
- The documentation states that one can use `--directories-to-pull /storage`. However, this results in an error saying that the path `/storage` is not known. Why is that?